# Web Audio API play sound to specific speaker/channel

Tags: audio, 3d, web-audio-api, surround

I am attempting to play sound out of a specific speaker other than left or right in a surround sound system.  I can easily switch between left and right channel, but cannot get sound from any other speaker.  Tried on Firefox and Chrome.

```
<script>
context = new AudioContext();
function playSound()
{
    var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
    oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
    var mergerNode = context.createChannelMerger(6);
    var silence = context.createBufferSource();
    silence.connect(mergerNode, 0, 0);
    silence.connect(mergerNode, 0, 1);
    silence.connect(mergerNode, 0, 2);
    silence.connect(mergerNode, 0, 3);
    silence.connect(mergerNode, 0, 4);
    oscillator.connect(mergerNode, 0, 5);
    mergerNode.connect(context.destination);
    currentTime = context.currentTime;
    oscillator.start(currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(currentTime + 2);    
}
playSound();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a pannerNode? Not the stereoPannerNode, but the regular pannerNode, which does 3d panning.  I imagine if you position the sound source behind the audio listener, you'll hear the sound come out of your rear speakers.

Comment: Yep, that is the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately what they seem to mean with "3D" is left right, and **Distance** .  I tried every which way I can think of and have been unable to get anything but left and right sounds.